# How to recognize that a hard cheese is mouldy?

Tags: food-safety, cheese, mold

I have a piece of comte (French hard cheese) open for some time (1 week or so). How do I recognize that it's moldy and therefore not good to eat? There're a thin non-connected layer flour on the piece of the cheese which makes it quite difficult to visually detect mold.

Comment: You see the mold?  Perhaps there is something about this question that I am not understanding.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I see _something_, but there is something (probably flour) on these packed cheeses from the very beginning.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a picture, then...

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I would like to, but the only camera I have is my webcam, and I doubt anything can be seen there.

Comment: When you say non-connected... is the floury stuff on the rind of the cheese? Or the actual surface of the cheese?

Comment: @Jefromi on both, actually :-/

Comment: Cheese does not have *flour* on it... are you talking about a rind, or white spots i.e. mold?

Comment: A picture would be *really* helpful here; I don't think any of us have any idea what this layer you're talking about is, especially if it's already there when you buy the cheese, including on the actual cheese, not just the rind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the cheese should look like.

[image: Comté Cheese]

Edges on a cheese like this are referred to as the rind. Any white on there is fine unless it starts looking fluffy, even then you could probably just cut it off. The rind here and on many hard cheeses is a quite hard layer of dried cheese and protects the cheese inside.

If the yellow section of the cheese had mold on it that would indicate the cheese had become moldy after being cut or if there was a blue or green mold growing anywhere on this type of cheese. This would normally indicate the cheese had been kept badly. If your fridge is clean and dry wrapped hard cheese should keep a couple of months.

Comment: you are absolutely right.i followed the same method to keep cheese.

Answer (score 1):

to see if a hard cheese like comte is rotting, you can usually smell it but i assume you may not be used to the original taste. If it is really not good for eating, some moss will start to developp on, this will happen when it is kept in a humid place; if you are keeping the cheese in a dry place it will just become hard as hell and if it start to get cracks on the surface, the taste can be not so good.